# Logging request time of a Play!2 Scala application

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to log the time of all requests in a Scala Play!2 app.  I think I need to override `onRequestReceived` to return a new `Handler` that calls the action, then logs the time, then returns the result of the action.  But I don't know how to call the handler.

Here's what I have:

```
override def onRequestReceived(requestHeader: RequestHeader) = {
  val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis

  val (rh, handler) = super.onRequestReceived(requestHeader)

  def newHandler = Action {
    val result = handler.apply // No such method

    val requestTime = System.currentTimeMillis - startTime
    Logger.debug("time: " + requestTime)

    result
  }

  (rh, newHandler)
}
```

But handler.apply does not exist.  How do I call the handler that super.onRequestReceived returned.  And, more importantly, am I going about this the right way?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/kenshoo/metrics-play).

Comment: I saw that, but `Filter`s only work for requests that get a handler.  I need to log all the requests, even the unsuccessful ones.

Comment: Would you want to log this outside of play? Or any time spent in play internals will be excluded.. I would think network level logging for most accurate, or at the network boundaries (between nic and ngnx) on the machine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, instead of trying to handle the task of handling the request by yourself, why not just call the base class and log the time that the method in the base class takes to handle it? In other words:

```
override def onRequestReceived(request: RequestHeader) = {
  val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
  val result = super.onRequestReceived(request)
  val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
  logger.debug("Request lasted:" + (endTime - startTime) + " ms")
  result
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's much cleaner than what I was trying.